# My galaxy S2 battery loses all of it's charge in about 6 hours of minimal use

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, battery-life

I switched over to an old phone (like a really old phone) from a windows phone, due to the limitations of that app store. However, I have noticed that it quickly discharges with not much use. I have done the battery spin test and it did not spin like a top necessarily, but did spin a little bit. The white strip is white, so there is no water damage. How can I find out what is causing this. PS. i ordered a new battery and it is coming by next Friday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My samsung galaxy 2 battery is draining to fast!](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/41217/7574)

Answer (score 0):

Try the extra battery when you get it but in the meantime look up how to calibrate your battery with or without root (depending on your setup (if you don't know what root is you probably don't have it and it's probably not worth messing around with) .  There is an app on the play store called battery calibration pro that should work without root. Also try booting your phone into safe mode (look it up) and going through a day like that, if your battery life is better it may be an app that you downloaded causing the battery loss. Either way go to settings, more, battery and looking at what is using up your battery. Also, consider buying an extra battery charger to charge two batteries a night and swap them out during the day or buying an extra battery case.